# Is it possible to change command time out in EF migration's Up method?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Is it possbile to change the following query's time out inside the Up method? It takes about 10 mins to run, so it will throw time out error with the default time out (3 mins). I don't want to change the time out setting in DbContext as this query is the only one that takes so long. I want to set a new time out specific at this command level.

```
public partial class sqlQery : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Sql(@"UPDATE[MyTable] SET[SomeValue] = 0;");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
```

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? EF Core has options to alleviate this: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/317/extending-the-command-timeout-in-entity-framework-core-migrations

Comment: I am using .NET 4.6.1  and EF 6.1.3